# SharePoint Online - filter lookup text field on new item form to current user

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, filter

I have 2 lists:

1. Traveler:

   - **Employee** - `Text` (Ex:'Smith, John')
   - **Profile link** - `Url`
2. Travel Authorization Request:

   - **Traveling Employee** - `Lookup` "Traverler:Employee"

I need to apply a filter to the **Traveling Employee** field on the new item form so that the only selection a user is allowed to select is their name (or any text close to it), with little to no code.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering a lookup column based on the logged in user isn't possible out of the box. You might be able to do that using some javascript on the page. If you're going to use that approach I would simply use a person/group field with multiple people in the field which they are able to choose.

But I really want to ask what the purpose is here - and if theres a reason why you can't use the build in "created by" column that always gets populated with the logged in user who created the item.